# In Mscrm 4.0 how can a form be readonly, including the relationship link

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

In MS CRM 4.0 how can a form be readonly, including the relationship link. Clicking the link must show readonly forms of related entities as well (if main entity is readonly even realtions must appear as readonly whereas its not.).

Answer (score 0):

CRM doesn't give you a means to do that. You'd have to do some (not only "some", actually) very heavy DOM manipulation, and there might be places you just have no chance of getting to.

(It'd be fun to at least try and see how far you can really get, though.)

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the create, edit, delete asign and asign to permissions for the user/role and entity you want to be readonly.